# What does the notation $[R':x]_R$ mean in this context?

Tags: ring-theory, notation, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring and $R'$ an overring of $R$. What does $[R':x]_R$ mean for $x \in R'$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the context. Because of your title it reminds me on the *ideal quotient*.

**Definition:** Let $I,J$ be ideals in a ring $R$. Then
$$
(I:J)_R=(I:J)=\{a\in R\mid aJ\subseteq I\}
$$
is the ideal quotient. Here $(I:x):=(I:(x))$, where $(x)$ is the principal ideal generated by $x$.

Comment: that's it! i thought of it but i figured it would be better to ask. it was about ideal quotients, but i wasn't understanding the little R attatched to the quotient. thank you